PHP function supposed to return a DOMElement object always returns NULL
I'm trying to write a function that will receive a DOMElement object, perform some seeking operations within its descendants and then return the DOMElement corresponding to the wanted parameters.
XML fragment:
        <Subsection lims:inforce-start-date="2004-08-31" lims:fid="279739" lims:id="279739">
            <MarginalNote lims:inforce-start-date="2004-08-31" lims:fid="279740" lims:id="279740">Tax payable by non-resident persons</MarginalNote>
            <Label>(3)</Label>
            <Text>Where a person who is not taxable under subsection 2(1) for a taxation year</Text>
            <Paragraph lims:inforce-start-date="2004-08-31" lims:fid="279741" lims:id="279741">
                <Label>(a)</Label>
                <Text>was employed in Canada,</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph lims:inforce-start-date="2004-08-31" lims:fid="279742" lims:id="279742">
                <Label>(b)</Label>
                <Text>carried on a business in Canada, or</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph lims:inforce-start-date="2004-08-31" lims:fid="279743" lims:id="279743">
                <Label>(c)</Label>
                <Text>disposed of a taxable Canadian property,</Text>
            </Paragraph>
            <ContinuedSectionSubsection lims:inforce-start-date="2004-08-31" lims:fid="279744" lims:id="279744">
                <Text>at any time in the year or a previous year, an income tax shall be paid, as required by this Act, on the person’s taxable income earned in Canada for the year determined in accordance with Division D.</Text>
            </ContinuedSectionSubsection>
        </Subsection>

Function:
function untilUHitText($domElement){
    echo "<br>DomElement analyzed: <br>";
    var_dump($domElement);
    if($domElement->tagName == "Text" || $domElement->childElementCount == 0){
        return $domElement;
    } else {
        untilUHitText($domElement->lastElementChild);
    }
}

Code calling the function (for testing purposes):
$appendHere = untilUHitText($weirdo->previousSibling);
var_dump($appendHere);

The function will be called every time there is a tag containing "Continued" such as the ContinuedSectionSubsection tag in the above XML, and should return the last Text DOMElement of its previous sibling.
The var_dump in the function will show the passed DOMElement without any issue, but the returned $domElement is always null, even though I do not perform any operations on it.
I have tried changing the code within the function, but as soon as I perform any check on $domElement, it just returns a null value.

return null implies that your if statement is not true so is not running.

tagName's value should be all lowercase. So $domElement->tagName == "Text" is not met, and no return value is given what matches to null.

If that is truly your function, then maybe consider throwing an exception when your if logic isn't true

I added more details for clarity. The tags are all capitalized so I have to call them as they are written.

The recursive call needs to be in a return statement.
